# Message from `ClusterReceptionist` doesn't reach `DistributedPubSubMediator`

Tags: scala, akka, cluster-computing, distributed

I'm trying to send a simple string `"Dummy string"` to an Akka cluster via `ClusterClient`. The settings are fine, I got frontend and cluster connected, but the `Send` message sent to `DistributedPubSub` mediator from `ClusterReceptionist` is delivered to `DeadLetters`.

If I schedule another `Send` message to be sent to the mediator some time later from inside the cluster, it works.

Please help, thank you in advance.

Frontend logs:

```
22:51:34,645 DEBUG akka.remote.EndpointWriter - sending message RemoteMessage: [Send(user/UserServiceProxy,Dummy string,true)] to [Actor[akka.tcp://PvpCluster@127.0.0.1:2552/system/receptionist#-1744655285]]<+[akka.tcp://PvpCluster@127.0.0.1:2552/system/receptionist] from [Actor[akka://PvpFrontend/deadLetters]]
22:51:34,646 DEBUG akka.serialization.Serialization(akka://PvpFrontend) - Using serializer [akka.cluster.pubsub.protobuf.DistributedPubSubMessageSerializer] for message [akka.cluster.pubsub.DistributedPubSubMediator$Send]
```

Cluster logs:

```
22:51:34,626 DEBUG akka.remote.EndpointWriter - sending message RemoteMessage: [ActorIdentity([B@11b5bea7,Some(Actor[akka://PvpCluster/system/receptionist#-1744655285]))] to [Actor[akka.tcp://PvpFrontend@localhost:3000/user/cluster-client#-2107174838]]<+[akka.tcp://PvpFrontend@localhost:3000/user/cluster-client] from [Actor[akka://PvpCluster/deadLetters]]
22:51:34,654 DEBUG akka.remote.EndpointWriter - received local message RemoteMessage: [Send(user/UserServiceProxy,Dummy string,true)] to [Actor[akka://PvpCluster/system/receptionist#-1744655285]]<+[akka://PvpCluster/system/receptionist] from [Actor[akka.tcp://PvpFrontend@localhost:3000/deadLetters]()]
22:51:34,657 DEBUG akka.cluster.client.ClusterReceptionist$Internal$ClientResponseTunnel - started (akka.cluster.client.ClusterReceptionist$Internal$ClientResponseTunnel@476348f0)
22:51:34,657 DEBUG akka.cluster.client.ClusterReceptionist - now supervising Actor[akka://PvpCluster/system/receptionist/akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FPvpFrontend%40localhost%3A3000%2FdeadLetters#552013204]
22:51:34,657 INFO akka.actor.RepointableActorRef - Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://PvpCluster/system/receptionist/akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FPvpFrontend%40localhost%3A3000%2FdeadLetters#552013204] to Actor[akka://PvpCluster/system/distributedPubSubMediator#-1480760039] was not delivered. [5] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
22:51:34,892 DEBUG akka.serialization.Serialization(akka://PvpCluster) - Using serializer [akka.serialization.JavaSerializer] for message [akka.remote.Ack]
22:51:36,439 DEBUG akka.remote.EndpointWriter - received local message RemoteMessage: [Heartbeat] to [Actor[akka://PvpCluster/system/receptionist#-1744655285]]<+[akka://PvpCluster/system/receptionist] from [Actor[akka.tcp://PvpFrontend@localhost:3000/user/cluster-client#-2107174838]()]
22:51:36,440 DEBUG akka.cluster.client.ClusterReceptionist - Received new contact from [akka.tcp://PvpFrontend@localhost:3000/user/cluster-client]
22:51:36,440 DEBUG akka.remote.EndpointWriter - sending message RemoteMessage: [HeartbeatRsp] to [Actor[akka.tcp://PvpFrontend@localhost:3000/user/cluster-client#-2107174838]]<+[akka.tcp://PvpFrontend@localhost:3000/user/cluster-client] from [Actor[akka://PvpCluster/system/receptionist#-1744655285]]
22:51:36,837 DEBUG akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor - stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure exactly without seeing code, but typically this would happen because you have forgotten to register the recipient to the cluster client receptionist, or the registration has not happened yet on the cluster node when the client sends a message (a race condition).

If a message reaches the receptionist and there is no such path registered the message goes to `deadLetters`.

Registering the node to the receptionist is done like this (sample from [the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-client.html#an-example)):

```
val serviceA = system.actorOf(Props[Service], "serviceA")
ClusterClientReceptionist(system).registerService(serviceA)
```